# can't register my variable in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

i get an error when i clic on my button sumbit 
the error say undefined method `strftime' for nil:NilClass

when i debugge my application i see something strange

```
tarted POST "/users/2/calendars" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-05-24 19:44:25 +0200
Processing by CalendarsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"8l0+IDaC+tAHdQi+yvpnWEJRHrR8hNwBA3zgaSBoovQ=", "calendar"=>{"event"=>"aze", "published_on"=>"2013-05-07", "description"=>"rrrrrrr"}, "commit"=>"Create Calendar", "user_id"=>"2"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO `calendars` (`created_at`, `description`, `event`, `published_on`, `updated_at`, `user_id`) VALUES ('2013-05-24 17:44:26', NULL, NULL, NULL, '2013-05-24 17:44:26', 2)
   (79.8ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://127.0.0.1:3000/users/2/calendars/39
Completed 302 Found in 93ms (ActiveRecord: 80.3ms)
cache: [GET /users/2/calendars/39] miss
```

why he doesn't take my variable event, published_on  description  i dont understand . 
i have missing something  ?

calendar.model

```
class Calendar < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :event, :published_on, :description, :user_id
    belongs_to :user#, :foreign_key => :user_id
end
```

user.model

```
has_many :calendar#, :foreign_key => :user_id
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :calendar
  #attr_accessible :calendar_id
end
```

**calendar.controler**

```
  def index
     @user = current_user
    #@content_calendars = @user.Calendar
    @content_calendars = @user.Calendar.all
    @content_calendars_by_dates = @content_calendars.group_by(&:published_on)
    @date = params[:date] ? Date.parse(params[:date]) : Date.today
  end

  def show
    @user = current_user
   # @calendar = @user.find_all_calendar_by()
    #  @tasks = @project.tasks.find_all_by_complete(false)
    @calendar = @user.calendar.find(params[:id])
  end





  def new

    @user = current_user
    @calendar = @user.calendar.new
   #@calendar = @user.calendar.build
  end

  # GET /calendars/1/edit
  def edit
    @user = current_user
    @calendar = @user.Calendar.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /calendars
  # POST /calendars.json
  def create

    @user = current_user
    @calendar = @user.calendar.new(params[:current_user])
    #@calendar = @user.Calendar.new(params[:calendar])
    if @calendar.save
       #redirect_to calendar_path(@user)
       redirect_to [@user,@calendar]
       #, notice: "L evenement a ete cree"
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  # PUT /calendars/1
  # PUT /calendars/1.json
  def update
 @user = current_user
    @calendar = @user.Calendar.find(params[:id])
      if @calendar.update_attributes(params[:id])
          redirect_to [@user, @calendar]#, notice: "L article a ete mis a jour"
        else
          render :edit
      end
    end

  # DELETE /calendars/1
  # DELETE /calendars/1.json
  def destroy
 @user = current_user
    @calendar.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to calendars_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

private
  def find_user 
    @user = current_user
    #@user = User.first
    #@user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
    #findession[:user_id]) 
  end
```

thanks again for your help guy

Comment: Please edit your question and add the `CalendarsController` code.

Comment: Also your form may be invalid, because submitted parameters should contain not `calendar` hash, but `calendar_attributes`. Do you use nested forms?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand where you are facing error, so please paste the code of Controller. Based on your explanation, I am feeling that you should get calender's parameter like below. I think your controller should create object like this from calender parameters:

```
@calender = Calender.new(params[:calender])
@calender.user_id = params[:user_id]
```

Hope that helps!!!